# I currently have OS 10.6 want to upgrade OS

Tags: macos, adobe

I currently have OS 10.6 - Safari and other browsers are no longer supported.
My problem is I have Adobe CS4 Design and web software and I don't have a few thousand dollars hanging about to upgrade CS4
SO.....
Does Lion work with Adobe CS4 - or should I just start saving my pennies for more expensive software?
I had heard that OS 10.6 was the highest OS I could get with CS4.

Comment: I'm sure I'm not the first person to suggest this to you, but consider upgrading to Creative Cloud. I was in the same boat you are - I had the CS3 Master Collection, and couldn't afford to replace it. I waited until Adobe had a promotion, and I have the Creative Cloud "All Apps" package and I'm paying $29/mo. The price for one app is currently $20/mo. Being able to upgrade my OS -and- my Adobe products has been well worth it.

Comment: Not sure about CS4, but I have CS5 or 5.5 and when I upgraded from 10.7 to 10.11, I had a little trouble at first and had to download special legacy Java, but it's pretty much fine now.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can use CS4 with Mavericks according [to Adobe's site](https://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/global/mac-os-mavericks-compatability.html).

> Is Adobe aware of any major issues, bugs, or odd user experiences when
>   using CS5, CS4, or CS3 products with Mac OS X Mavericks (10.9)?
>
> Yes, Adobe Drive could cause the opening or saving of files to take
>   longer. See Files open, save slowly for more information.

Comment: Thank you - I was hoping that even upgrading to OS 10.7 (Lion) would be enough to be able to use browsers, I have been anxious about messing up what I have - and even 29 a month is a stretch for a retired person on a budget. CS4 works just fine and dandy for my needs - but then when you can't use the internet reliably because the browser isn't supported by your OS system - well - it's downright depressing!

Comment: Be sure you do a backup first, just in case something, anything, goes wrong.  Also, if this answer addresses your question, be sure to [accept it](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) in order to help others.